# Draw multiple canvas from inputs and calculate how to align them

Tags: javascript, html, css

A small project is on following address: [PLEASE CLICK HERE](https://jevtic.co/ts/)

Plan is to draw multiple rectangle in canvas based on user input (width, height, color) and align them in field bellow and to take smaller area as possible. Field is Grid Preview.

Current JavaScript that successfully draw one rectangle is:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasgrid');
canvas.width = 855;
canvas.height = 500;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function draw(){
    var x = document.getElementById("width").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("height").value;
    var boja = document.getElementById("color").value;
    var arr = [x,y,boja];
    let pos = {x: 0, y: 0};
    arr.forEach(p => {
        context.rect(pos.x, pos.y, p.w, p.h);
        pos.x += p.w; // should return to zero at the edge of the canvas
        pos.y += p.h;
        context.beginPath();
        context.stroke();
        context.fillStyle = boja;
        context.fill();
        context.fillStyle = "white";
        context.font="bold 10px sans-serif";
        context.textAlign="center"; 
        context.textBaseline = "middle";
        context.fillText(x+'x'+y, 10+(x/2),10+(y/2));
    });
}
```

I do have a problem loading other inputs, after user click on green button.
Color JavaScript plugin that I am using is [jsoclor](http://jscolor.com/), also not sure how to load it in each duplicated field.

Please let me know if any additional info is needed. All codes can be seen in source files via mentioned link.

Thanks.

Comment: Your demo doesn't even draw one rectangle, perhaps because context.stroke() is commented out. To draw additional rectangles you would have to adapt the first two arguments to context.rect() according to user input and your canvas dimensions.

Comment: Strange, since I was able to draw even with that line commented. That line is not commented now, and able to draw rectangle. Since mu knowledge of JS is not advanced, can you please clarify what do you mean by adopt? Since I already have:

`context.rect(10,5,x1,y1)`

Comment: By adapt I mean you have to vary the rectangle's x- and y-position or you'd be simply overwriting previous ones.

Comment: And that is my original question here :-) Since not sure how to do it.

Comment: In this setup arr will ever only have one entry, the initial. You need to have it populated with all the values from the form, storing each line/rect in an object and pushing it onto arr.

Comment: I am just getting into the loop with myself :-)
Is it near like this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_foreach

Comment: You need to start with the form and on its submission push each fieldset onto arr. You then can use the function as described. I've created a rough and incomplete demo of what I think it is you're trying to achieve: https://codepen.io/AndreNuechter/pen/LaLmeY

Comment: Thank you. I will study that example and to implement into demo.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to let me know if my answer helped you, by accepting and upvoting it ;)

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer might be to store the user input in an array of objects (eg [{w: ..., h: ..., color: ...}, {...}...]) and iterate over that in your function.

In your function you might then have something like the following:

```
let pos = {x: 0, y: 0};
arr.forEach(p => {
  context.rect(pos.x, pos.y, p.w, p.h);
  pos.x += p.w; // should return to zero at the edge of the canvas
  //pos.y += left as an exercise to the reader ;)
});
```

Comment: I tried all various combination, but not working. I guess I did not defined array with correct elements?

`function draw(){
var x = document.getElementById("width").value;
var y = document.getElementById("height").value;
var boja = document.getElementById("color").value;
var arr = [x,y,boja];
let pos = {x: 0, y: 0};
arr.forEach(p => {
context.rect(pos.x, pos.y, p.w, p.h);
pos.x += p.w; // should return to zero at the edge of the canvas
pos.y += p.h;
context.beginPath();
context.stroke();
context.fillStyle = boja;
context.fill();
        });
            `

Comment: Can you edit in your adaptations in your original question? It`s kinda hard to read it like that.

Comment: Yes, just did, sorry for that.

Comment: Maybe something like this: 
`var arr =  [{w:w.value, h:h.value, boja:boja.value}];`
Of course, not working, as I said, still learning this JS and head is about to explode. :-)